# SUM CASE - Don't Display record if NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I'm using the following statement:

```
    SELECT 
        Number As [ACCOUNT NUMBER],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Paid_Pmt_Dt] >= '05/01/2014'
        AND[Paid_Pmt_Dt] <= '05/31/2014' AND [Total_Pmt_Amt] > '0' THEN Total_Pmt_Amt End) [MAY],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Paid_Pmt_Dt] >= '06/01/2014'
        AND[Paid_Pmt_Dt] <= '06/30/2014' AND [Total_Pmt_Amt] > '0' THEN Total_Pmt_Amt End) [JUNE]
    FROM Gross_Pmt
    GROUP BY Number
```

In some cases there is no Payment during either of the two months - in these cases I'm seeing NULL for both months.  Is there a way when this occurs to not display the record if both months are NULL?

Comment: Please specify the DBMS you are using.

Comment: You can put in a where clause WHERE Month(Paid_Pmt_Dt) NOT in (5,6). It would filter out the rows

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Number As [ACCOUNT NUMBER],
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN 
            [Paid_Pmt_Dt] >= '05/01/2014' AND
            [Paid_Pmt_Dt] <= '05/31/2014' AND 
            [Total_Pmt_Amt] > '0' 
        THEN Total_Pmt_Amt 
        END) [MAY],
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN 
            [Paid_Pmt_Dt] >= '06/01/2014' AND
            [Paid_Pmt_Dt] <= '06/30/2014' AND 
            [Total_Pmt_Amt] > '0' 
        THEN Total_Pmt_Amt 
        END) [JUNE]
FROM Gross_Pmt
WHERE Paid_Pmt_Dt >= '05/01/2014' AND Paid_Pmt_Dt <= '6/30/2014'
GROUP BY Number
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to solve this:

1. Add a WHERE clause to filter only dates in the two months
2. Add a HAVING clause to filter SUMs that are not null
3. Wrap the query up as an inner query and use a WHERE clause on the SUM result columns to specify they are not both null

Option 1. is the more efficient and easiest to code. Add this WHERE clause to your query:

```
...
FROM ...
WHERE Paid_Pmt_Dt BETWEEN '05/01/2014' AND '06/30/2014'
GROUP BY ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add month and year to the group by clause

```
SELECT Number [ACCOUNT NUMBER],YEAR([Paid_Dmt_Dt]) YYYY,MONTH([Paid_Dmt_Dt]) MM,SUM(Total_Pmt_Amt) GrossTotal
FROM Gross_Pmt 
GROUP BY Number, YEAR([Paid_Dmt_Dt]),MONTH([Paid_Dmt_Dt])
```

This eliminates empty months by default. You also do not need `[Total_Pmt_Amt] > '0'`.

This will return one row for each month but i think you can use this as a base for PIVOT or work with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you simply want to filter the rows where both calculated columns return NULL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (

    SELECT 
        Number As [ACCOUNT NUMBER],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Paid_Pmt_Dt] >= '05/01/2014'
        AND[Paid_Pmt_Dt] <= '05/31/2014' AND [Total_Pmt_Amt] > '0' THEN Total_Pmt_Amt End) [MAY],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Paid_Pmt_Dt] >= '06/01/2014'
        AND[Paid_Pmt_Dt] <= '06/30/2014' AND [Total_Pmt_Amt] > '0' THEN Total_Pmt_Amt End) 
    FROM Gross_Pmt
    GROUP BY Number
  ) as dt
WHERE [MAY] IS NOT NULL OR [JUNE] IS NOT NULL
```